# Display Text Where SQL Result Is 1

Tags: sql

I am running the following query

```
SELECT accounts.name, accounts_cstm.account_number_c,validated_c,chkcustomer_c, 
users.user_name FROM
accounts_cstm
LEFT OUTER JOIN
accounts
ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
users
ON accounts.assigned_user_id = users.id WHERE accounts.name = '1234'
```

here is my result in my web application[image]

I want to display yes or no in validated and customer

1 will = yes and 0 will = no

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT accounts.name, accounts_cstm.account_number_c,
    CASE 
        WHEN validated_c = 1
        THEN 'yes' 
        ELSE 'no' 
    END as validated
,chkcustomer_c,users.user_name FROM...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE` SQL statement like this :

```
SELECT 
    […], 
    CASE validated 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'yes' 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'no'
    END
FROM …
```